# php script does not show all images stored in a table

Tags: php, android

in mysql Datbase there is images stored using php Script (image got from a form.html/POST method) let's cal them (phpImages). and there is others stored using android application ( by converting Bitmap to String and using StringBuilder ). let's call them (androidImages).

with this php script i can load and display phpImages, but i cannot display androidImages.

```html
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","othmane") or die(mysqli_error($con));
  
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET'){
$id = $_GET['id']; 
$sql = "SELECT image FROM images WHERE id = '$id'";

$r = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));;
  
$result=mysqli_fetch_array($r);

header('Content-Type:image/jpeg');

echo ( $result['image']);
mysqli_close($con);
}
?>
```

with this php script i can load androidImages, but i cannot load phpImages :

```html
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","othmane") or die(mysqli_error($con));
  
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET'){
$id = $_GET['id']; 
$sql = "SELECT image FROM images WHERE id = '$id'";

$r = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));;
  
$result=mysqli_fetch_array($r);

header('Content-Type:image/jpeg');

echo base64_decode( $result['image'] );
mysqli_close($con);
}
?>
```

i wan't a php script that could display the both. because i want to load all images in a ListView of an android Apps.

**This is php script relied to android Application : **

```html
<?php
 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
  
  $image = $_POST['image'];
  
  $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","othmane")or die(mysqli_error($con));
  
  $sql = "INSERT INTO images (image,image_type) VALUES (?,'android')";
  
  $stmt = mysqli_prepare($con,$sql);
  
  mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"s",$image);
  mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
  
  $check = mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt);
  
  if($check == 1){
   echo "Image Uploaded Successfully";
  }else{
   echo "Error Uploading Image";
  }
  mysqli_close($con);
 }else{
  echo "Error";
 }
 ?>
```

this is php Script relied with Form.html post method :

```html
<?php
echo ini_get( 'file_uploads' );

if(!isset($_POST['submit'])){
 echo '<p>Please Select Image to Upload</p>';
 }
else
 {
 try {
 upload();
 }
 catch(Exception $e)
 {
 echo '<h4>'.$e->getMessage().'</h4>';
 }
 }

function upload(){
 $imgfp = fopen($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], 'rb');
 print_r($_FILES);
 
 $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=othmane", 'root', '');

 $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

 $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO images (image,image_type) VALUES (?,'php')");

 $stmt->bindParam(1, $imgfp, PDO::PARAM_LOB);

 $stmt->execute();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a column called `image_type` in your table and pass one of the following values to determine what the source of the image is upon uploading: `phpImage` or `androidImage`

So you can do:

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","othmane") or die(mysqli_error($con));

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET'){
        $id = $_GET['id']; 
        $sql = "SELECT image, image_type FROM images WHERE id = '$id'";

        $r = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));

        $result = mysqli_fetch_array($r);

        header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

        if ($result['image_type'] == 'phpImage') {
            echo ( $result['image']);
        } else if ($result['image_type'] == 'androidImage') {
            echo base64_decode( $result['image'] );
        }

        mysqli_close($con);
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks , this is a good way to resolve the problem , but why is there difference between the androidImage and phpImage ?! 
I also noticed that the size of androidImages is so big ; even when i store the same image the android One is bigger x3 times than the php one !

Comment: @OtmàaneFikri "Very roughly, the final size of Base64-encoded binary data is equal to 1.37 times the original data size" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64 

That might be the reason! So you have to crop it manually :)

Comment: yes when the image is encoded its size become bigger when it is stored in the database, thank you :)))